# php artisan queue:work command not working

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-queue

I use queues and have a jobs table in database. jobs are inserted to jobs table but when enter "php artisan queue:work --queue=something" command nothing happens. I have another project which use the same .env file and same queue and it works correctly. I have tried php artisan config:clear but it is still the same. What is the problem?

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\deneme> php artisan queue:work 
PHP Warning:  Module "mysqli" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

```php
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Comment: The error is indicating you're trying to load the mysqli extension twice. Check your php.ini that is used for the CLI PHP

Comment: It's just a warning. That's not the cause.

Answer (score 2):

use queue connection, not queue driver.

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Comment: Maybe cache was not clear, so remove folder  storage/framework/cache and bootstrap/cache/ contents